# How can I determine number of blocks in sctp package?

Tags: networking, sctp

SCTP protocol has the following format of packages:
 - Source Port Number
 - Destination Port Number
 - Verification Tag
 - Checksum
 - N chunks

I'm trying to write low-lever parser of the protocol, but I don't know, how to determine number of chunks in the SCTP package.
Thanks!

Comment: How big is the "N chunks" field, what's its byte order and what code do you have so far?

Comment: N chunks isn't a field. I mean it is one or more data blocks. Each block has a specific format, but I haven't found information about number the data blocks in the package or maybe the last block should be marked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the chunk headers. Each one contains a 16-bit length field, after the 8-bit type & 8-bit flags fields. Remember that all numeric values in SCTP are in network byte order (big-endian).

The chunk fields are documented in [RFC 4960 section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960#section-3.2):

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |   Chunk Type  | Chunk  Flags  |        Chunk Length           |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   \                                                               \
   /                          Chunk Value                          /
   \                                                               \
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Chunks begin after the [SCTP Common Header Field Descriptions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960#section-3.1).

By reading the Chunk Length field you can skip its payload and find the start of the next chunk. Do this repeatedly until you reach the end of the IP packet.

The chunk's length includes the four bytes that constitute the type, flags & length fields.